# windows 10, Xampp, Apache will not start, port 80 in use

Tags: xampp, windows-10, port80

Trying to install and launch Apache from Xampp...
Error message:
"Problem detected! Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!"
No answer found in previous posts.

ctrl+alt+del >details give:  PID4: Système et mémoire compressée
fichier ntoskrnl.exe,  fin de tâche impossible

Xampp suggests: "reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port"
port 80 appears in
- apache config > httpd.conf (listen 80) and Servername localhost: 80
- confif > service and port settings > only for Apache mainport 80

Will it be  enough to change these two value eg to 8080 as some posts suggest?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 8):

Port 80 is used by IIS (Internet Information Service) or (World Wide Web Publishing Service).
I had the same problem and i found a way to fix the problem.
You can either go to processes and stop the iis service or you can open **"PowerShell"** with **administrator** rights and type like this.

> iisreset /stop

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in addition to updating the httpd.conf to listen on 80, you should do as the message suggests, ie click config on the top right of the XAMP panel, then click "Service and Port Settings" and set the port to 88 (or whatever you use.  If you do not do this, the XAMP control panel will still be listening on 80 and you will get the error message since typically IIS is running there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in windows, i have followed following steps to resolve it.

- Go to Program And Feature from Control Panel
- Click on "Turn Windows Features On or Off" from the left side bar (Windows Features Modal will be opened)
- Find "Internet and Information Services" from the feature list
- Uncheck the checkbox of it

see the attached screenshots
[image]